# How to make vsCode be aware of deep dependency import for the autocompletion?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I've created multiple angular libraries which let me create website faster with bunch of components, eg: sidenav, cards, ...

I've created a "super library" that import all of them so I could just use `npm i myWebsiteBundle` to have every dependencies downloaded at once.

I've whiteListed every plugin like this in my `ng-package.json` file

```json
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "@myName/sidenav-conponent",
    "@myName/card-component",
  ]
```

But now, When I want to import it in eg. `app.module.ts` the vsCode import autocompletion wont find the module.

```js
import { SidenavComponentModule } from '@myName/card-component' // <-- Have to be typed manually

imports: [
  SidenavComponentModule // <-- No suggestion
]
```

*I know, it's recommended to download each package separately, but for my case it have to be implemented like this*

Does somebody already have faced the same problem and did found a solution to it?

#### Edit

I did then tried to export the library inside the `public-api.ts` file

```js
 export { SidenavComponentModule } from '@myName/card-component'
```

The autocompletion did show up, but it then failed to import the correct element.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export the components, modules, services, etc from the library.
**my-lib.ts**

```js
   // Public API Surface
    export * from './lib/my-lib.service';
    export * from './lib/my-lib.component';
    export * from './lib/my-lib.module';

    // AllowedNonPeerDependencies
    export { SidenavComponentModule } from '@myName/card-component'
```

Comment: It does not work, this show me the import suggestion but it point to the wrong file and fail to import it.