# Expose 3rd part library from own custom made library in angular

Tags: angular, npm, angular-library

I have the following project structure

> Library2 --->  Library1 (Library2 is install using npm to Library1)
>
> Library1 ---> clientApp1 (angular application) (then Library1 is install using npm to clientApp1)

Now I want to allow `clientApp1` to have access to `Library2` functionality. Is it possible to do it with `Library1` exposing `Library2` to `clientApp1`, instead of independently install `library2` to `clientApp1`

> NOTE: Want to access `Library2` functionalities that do not override into `Library1`

Comment: What do you mean by `NOTE: Want to access Library2 functionalities that do not override into Library1`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly your question.

You can add the third party library as dependencies of your custom library into the `package.json` file

```js
// projects/myCustomLibrary/package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/google-maps": "^11.2.4", // <-- third library
  }
```

Then add it as a white listed dependencies into the `ng-package.json`

```js
// projects/myCustomLibrary/ng-package.json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/website",
  "assets": ["./assets"],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "moment": "moment"
    }
  },
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "@angular/google-maps" // <-- here
  ]
}
```

then, we you do your `npm i myCustomlibrary` it will directly install de dependency and you'll be able to access it directly with your module like the following

```js
import { GoogleMapsModule } from '@angular/google-maps'
```

Be aware, vscode doesn't then find the auto import of those module, I've already opened a question for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65904037/how-to-make-vscode-be-aware-of-deep-dependency-import-for-the-autocompletion)